# Is there any way to make the Moon generate Earth terrain in Galacticraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

My question is about the Minecraft mod [Galacticraft](http://galacticraft.mods.wiki/wiki/Galacticraft).

I'm very curious about this, and I would like to attempt it. For science. Could I change the biome or dimension ID or something, to **make the Moon generate Earth terrain**?

Comment: Yes. It's called editing the code.

Answer (score -1):

Youwill need acces to the code to do that and change the terrain generation code yourself. This can therefor only be done if the mod is open source. You also will need to have a bit of java experience.

Comment: Wrong. You can decompile, edit and then recompile java. A great example is Minecraft, it isn't open source but it still can be modded.

Comment: yeah you try to mod minecraft without the external tools like forge or modloader?

Comment: How do you think how those work? They edit minecraft code so that you don't have to do it directly.